# chaning the class of menu item in the master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, menu

I have a menu item in a masterpage .. and i have used javascript to change the class when clicked.. It changes the class for a second but when its redirected to other pages it becomes the same.. Any idea how i should do it

I dont have access to the complete code rite now but it was something like this(i have used some alert box just to see whats happening..)

```
<style>
test1{ color: red;
   height:1000px;
      font-size:5px ;
       background-color:Aqua;
      } 

      test2 
      { font-family:Kozuka Mincho Pro M;
          color: red;
      font-size: 5px }
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastid = "";
function myFunc(id) {
    alert(id);
    if (lastid != "") {
        document.getElementById(lastid).removeAttribute("class", "test2");
        document.getElementById(lastid).setAttribute("class", "test1");
        var a = document.getElementById(lastid);

        alert(a.getAttribute("class"));

    }
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class", "test2");
    var cssid = id;
    $("#" + id).addClass('test1');


    alert(document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("class"));
    lastid = id;

}
    </script>


<li  id="firstry" onclick="myFunc(this.id);" ><a href="master-child.aspx"> Click</a> </li>
```

Comment: If you want the class value to persist across pages, you'll need to store the value of the class (as it relates to the user) somewhere, like a cookie, the session, or a DB. Since you are doing this in javascript, a cookie would prob be easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done this using Jquery .. it made things alot easier.. this goes through every link in the menu and then adds the class where it matches with the current page..
following is the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#subnav a').each(function (index) {
                if (this.href.trim() == window.location)
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
            });
        });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a class to the body tag that corresponds to the page name, and a CSS class.

```
<body id="home">
```

Then the css for the active menu item, assuming you have class names on your menu items:

```
#home li.firstitem { ... }
#about li.seconditem { ... }
```